# Not able to update Handlebars code with AJAX data

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a page in nodeJS written in handlebars which displays some graphs. Now i do an AJAX call and fetch some data from the backend. I want the page to get replaced with new data that the AJAX call got. I am not able to figure out how to do that.

This is the page that displays the graph with the AJAX call.

https://gist.github.com/alteclogitec1tikoonikhil/2557aaaf787945922ed269604a3df444

I am very new to AJAX with handlebars and templates. So no clue how to proceed from here.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058578/re-render-handlebars-template-after-ajax-response

Comment: Why are you templating a script?! Just wrap the AJAX call around your HighCharts instantation and append the data recieved from it (regarding your chart) and instantiate the chart with the data already there?

Comment: @Crowes Can you please elaborate a little bit? you can go through the gist once just to see what i am trying to do.